# How to remove the "Share this page" and other buttons from Chrome's omnibox (address bar)?

Tags: google-chrome

Google Chrome's omnibox (address bar) has added more cluttery buttons. How can I remove or hide these buttons?

[image: screenshot]

- open search in side panel
- install app
- share this page
- bookmark this tab

Answer (score 1):

#### How can I remove or hide these buttons?

1. Type `chrome://flags` in the address bar, and press <kbd>enter</kbd>
2. Search for "omnibox suggestion" and disable:

   - `chrome://flags/#omnibox-suggestion-button-row`
   - `chrome://flags/#omnibox-pedal-suggestions`
3. Chrome will ask you to restart the browser. Click on "Relaunch now" button to restart Google Chrome.

Sources:

- [Here’s How You Can Enable Google’s New “Chrome Actions” Feature / Digital Information World](https://www.digitalinformationworld.com/2020/11/heres-how-you-can-enable-googles-new.html)
- [[Tip] Enable or Disable Search Tips and Suggestions Buttons in Google Chrome Address bar – AskVG](https://www.askvg.com/tip-enable-or-disable-search-tips-and-suggestions-buttons-in-google-chrome-address-bar/)

Comment: Unfortunately, those flags seem to have been since removed from Chrome (I currently have Chrome 108).

Comment: @wisbucky: Still, this answer provides valuable links with info on what these buttons **are**... I just stumbled on them (not a regular Chrome user) and was surprised and clueless, so this answer was very helpful even if outdated about their removal.